# how to find Link-local (APIPA) address of another computer which is directly connected to my PC

Tags: link-local

My task is to SSH into an embedded (linux) computer system from my PC.
I have connected my PC directly to an embedded computer using LAN cable, both computers are configured to get IP address using DHCP.

Once the cable is plugged in, my PC gets a link-local IP address like: 169.254.11.114 .
The embedded computer doesn't have any monitor, keyboard connected to it so I cant see its IP address.

I'm carious if there's any way that I can find the embedded computer's link-local IP address ?!

Of course I know that I can use a DHCP server and connect the computers to it so I can  easily do this task, but my question is specially about finding link-local address of the other computer in a peer to peer connection.

Comment: use an ip scanner like nmap, it scans the /16 in less a minute

Comment: try `arp -a` command

Comment: @djdomi seems its taking much longer time for me, I'm using this command "nmap -sn -n -T5 169.254.0.0/16" but estimated time is around 53 minutes !!!

Comment: @4snok its only showing my local PC address !

Comment: can we please know, what is the OS of the systems that are being used?

Comment: Sure, my local PC has windows and the other system has Linux.

Comment: You may have not used the cheats table for nmap ;) you may want to use `–min-hostgroup 256` and maybe `–min-parallelism 256` where the first parameter is for host paralism and the second for ports, which will speed up the process insanely  256 is an example value and could/should be scaled on your system that is been used for